Is repeated measures ANOVA suit my method
I use a randomized, double-blind, placebo-controlled crossover method. Participants visit 4 times.
1 time for placebo at sea level,
1 time for placebo at hypoxia room,
1 time for beetroot at sea level,
1 time for beetroot at hypoxia room,
So I use G power to set repeated measures within factors, number of groups is 4.
is it suitable?

Your last line seems to refer to a specific software code/syntax, it's impossible to know if it's correct without knowing which software. Also, if this is a crossover design I assume you also have a between-subject factor of treatment order, so a mixed ANOVA would probable be more suitable than just RM-ANOVA.

sorry, I use G Power to set, just want to confirm whether the set is suitable or not

So you are doing a power calculation? Do you have a between-subject order factor in addition to the 4-level within-subjects factor?

I'm not sure what you are "setting" with G Power. I have a feeling there may be a language or translation issue. G Power is, AFAIK, for power calculations. As for what method you should use, I think RM ANOVA makes some unrealistic assumptions and a multilevel model might be better, but the details matterl

Assuming you only have the 4-level within-subject factor, to calculate sample size in GPower,

choose the "ANOVA: Repeated measures, within factors"

specify from "options" that you want to use effect size specification "as in Cohen (1988) - recommended".

then specify the effect size (in Cohen's f metric)

specify the desired power level (the default is .95, most want to use .80)

set number of groups to 1 (this is for between-subject factor levels)

and number of measurements to 4 (this is for within-subject factor levels)


Number of groups is for a potential between-subjects factor. If you have the between-subject factor of order of treatments, put the number of different orders into the number of groups box.
Steps 2 and 3 are very important (also that they are done in this order), because GPower defaults for effects size are not the best.

(+1) Do you think it would be possible to do a more precise power calculation by taking into account the crossover nature of the design? Admittedly, the OP hasn't explain how they are planning for this, if at all.

Thinking more about this. If we take the question statement at face value, "sea level" and "hypoxia room" cannot be considered a treatment. So more realistically that's a covariate/modifier while the treatment is placebo vs beet root.

Yes, I'm sure it would be more precise, but GPower doesn't seem to take that into account - all other things being equal it gives the same sample size estimate when you have just a within-subject factor as when you have a within and a between-subject factor. Same happens with WebPower's wp.rmanova. Simulation would be the best, but I don't know how to do it for mixed ANOVA.

And yes, OP would need to clarify, but it does sound like there are two within-subject factors - treatment and the "environment" or the like, and then perhaps a between-subject factor of order.
